# Custom UIView from XIB not resizing

Tags: xcode, uiview, xib, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

My aim is to create custom image for MKAnnotationView.
[image]

The number of "service items" in image can be different for every annotation -> it should be possible to dynamically change items in view.

My idea was to create custom UIView (xib), load xib programmatically and change items dynamically. Then I would convert UIView to UIImage.

//ServiceAnnotationView.xib

[image]

```
//ServiceAnnotationView.class
class ServiceAnnotationView: UIView{
    
}
```

//extension UIView -> possible to load xib file from code

```
extension UIView {
    class func fromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return Bundle(for: T.self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
    }
```

Creating annotation image dynamically.

```
let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
let serviceAnnotationView: ServiceAnnotationView = ServiceAnnotationView.fromNib()
view.image = serviceAnnotationView.asImage()
```

Result when showing 2 items:

[image]

Result when showing 1 items

[image]

In this case the UIView should automatically shrink.
The width of UIView is always the same. No matter how many items are present in UIStackView.

What I have tried so far?
I was trying to specify frame for UIView based on number of items. -> no success

Then I was changing constraint size of UIView based on number of items. -> no success

The UIView should automatically resize due to UIStackView. Why in this case is not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've left out a lot of information about your setup and how you're actually trying to use this, but this might help...

Assuming you have:

- some var/func in your `ServiceAnnotationView` to show/hide the images in the stack view
- you have a working `UIView` extension for `.asImage()`
- you've set sizing constraints on the images (e.g. Height and Width)

Call `.setNeedsLayout()` and `.layoutIfNeeded()` *before* calling `.asImage()`:

```
    let serviceAnnotationView: ServiceAnnotationView = ServiceAnnotationView.fromNib()

    // however you're setting the number of images to show in the stack view        
    serviceAnnotationView.numItems = 3
    
    serviceAnnotationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    serviceAnnotationView.setNeedsLayout()
    serviceAnnotationView.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    let img = serviceAnnotationView.asImage()
```